# HTACCESS Redirects and How to Properly Redirect to a domain to the Home Page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain: ***soloENEGYBAR.ca*** which is properly redirecting to ***soloNUTRITION.ca*** as long as it's http://

This does NOT WORK for https:// and errors (I do not know why).

---

**THE GOAL**

Is there a way to make it so the sub folders for ***soloenergybar.com*** ALSO redirect to the home page for ***solonutrition.ca***? As well as get this to work for http:// and https:// instead of just http://

For example, right now if I go to: ***soloenergybar.ca/en/home*** it redirects to ***solonutrition.ca/en/home*** which doesn't exist!

I would like to know if there's a way to force EVERY URL combo from ***soloenergybar.ca*** to go to the **home page** of ***solonutrition.ca*** vs adding the additional folder tree info /en/home/?

Thank you!

Current HTACCESS setting:

```js
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^132\.148\.131\.136
RewriteRule (.*) "https://www.solonutrition\.ca\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So `soloenergybar.ca/en/home` should redirect to `solonutrition.ca/`? What about `soloenergybar.ca/en/home/foo/bar` or `soloenergybar.ca/something` ?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes!  http:// and https:// soloenergybar.ca/anything-and-everything-uder-this-domain should redirect to the landing page for https://www.solonutrition.ca. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} soloenergybar\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.solonutrition.ca/? [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or test in a new browser to avoid old cache,